# What is the value of $32⊗34$?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

The operator $⊗$ acts on two numbers to give the following outcomes

$2⊗6 = 44$

$4 ⊗ 10 = 87$

$8 ⊗ 18 = 1613$

$16 ⊗ 22 = 2019$

What is the value of $32 ⊗ 34$?

I am trying to look for a pattern.

Any comments and suggestions on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated. Thank you!

(C) 2019 SASMO G7 Math Questions

Comment: Does F(32, 34) have to be a positive, whole number? If not, you could just solve $F(x,y)=axy + bx + cy + d$ for a,b,c,d and get some really, really ugly result for F(32,34)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It must be

> $3233$

because

> in each solution, the first half is the second number minus two, while the second half is the average of the two numbers being combined.

Or in symbols,

> $$a⊗b = (b-2)(\tfrac{a+b}{2}),$$ where the brackets denote concatenation.

I spotted this by noticing

> that each right-hand side seems to be in two parts concatenated together: e.g. the number $2019$ is not similar in size to $16$ and $22$, but the numbers $20$ and $19$ are. Then we can hunt for patterns in the two parts individually. I noticed the pattern in the second half first - it's always the midpoint of the two numbers being operated on - and then spotted the pattern in the first half which is even simpler.

Comment: I'm not sure that you have shown the "how" that the OP asks for. This is *an* answer, not necessarily unique.  What was your solving method?

Comment: @chasly I've expanded a bit more on my solving/spotting method, but note that there's never only one *possible* answer to this kind of question - you could use polynomial interpolation to find some horrible ugly function that satisfies the given criteria and then see what it spits out for the last one - although there should be only one *most neat/natural* answer.